# Toggles for chat notifications

Tags: feature-request, chat

Could there be a checkbox or some sort of option that allows the user to disable or enable chat notifications from a certain room?

Concept Art ([Icon](https://dev.twitter.com/docs/image-resources)):

> [image]

Here's a snap of what I go through **daily**:

[image]